# visual c++ create text file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++-cli

How to create text file?

```
CreateFile("1",            
               GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
               0,                    
               NULL,                 
               CREATE_NEW,        
               FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, 
               NULL);
```

throw

> 1>------ Build started: Project: test2, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
>   1>  test2.cpp
>   1>c:\users\kredkołamacz\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test2\test2\Form1.h(126): error C2065: 'GENERIC_READ' : undeclared identifier
>   1>c:\users\kredkołamacz\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test2\test2\Form1.h(126): error C2065: 'GENERIC_WRITE' : undeclared identifier
>   1>c:\users\kredkołamacz\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test2\test2\Form1.h(128): error C2065: 'NULL' : undeclared identifier
>   1>c:\users\kredkołamacz\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test2\test2\Form1.h(129): error C2065: 'CREATE_NEW' : undeclared identifier
>   1>c:\users\kredkołamacz\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test2\test2\Form1.h(130): error C2065: 'FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED' : undeclared identifier
>   1>c:\users\kredkołamacz\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test2\test2\Form1.h(131): error C2065: 'NULL' : undeclared identifier
>   1>c:\users\kredkołamacz\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test2\test2\Form1.h(125): error C3861: 'CreateFile': identifier not found
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: I think you need to include the header file for CreateFile()  -     WinBase.h (include Windows.h)  - from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Include the Windows header file as follows at the *top* of your `.h` or `.cpp` files:

```
#include <windows.h>
```

This should solve the problems related to undefined symbols such as `GENERIC_WRITE` and `CreateFile`. As another poster mentioned, you should typically write your code in `.cpp` files and only declare constants or classes in header files while placing the method implementations in `.cpp` files along with regular functions.

The issues related to `CreateFileW` once you get beyond this point need some more explanation:

By default, Windows applications generated from Visual Studio templates link against *Unicode* (wide character) versions of Windows APIs and have the `UNICODE` C/C++ preprocessor macro defined to indicate this. When `UNICODE` is defined, the preprocessor defines the symbol `CreateFile` to expand to the name of the actual underlying Windows function name which is `CreateFileW` where the `W` suffix indicates it is a "wide-character", i.e. Unicode, function. If the `UNICODE` macro is not defined (which can be overridden through various Visual Studio project settings), then `CreateFile` will expand to the `CreateFileA` symbol which is the name of the ANSI string version (`A` for ANSI) of the function. 99% of the time you should use the default settings for `UNICODE` as all modern versions of windows use Unicode characters internally.

Since `CreateFileW` takes Unicode string arguments you need to pass `L"1"` (i.e. a wide-character string literal) or use the `TEXT` macro (e.g. `TEXT("1")`) which will generate the correct string type corresponding to whether the `UNICODE` compiler switch is defined or not.

Here's a link to the MSDN article about `TEXT`: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374074%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Based on your error output you have the code in a header file.  You need to put the windows.h BEFORE the use of those symbols.  Generally you don't put code in header files.  (all the template nonsense notwithstanding)

Comment: When I add it to .h file:'CreateFileW' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [2]' to 'LPCWSTR'
1>          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

Comment: You are going to have to do at least a LITTLE work here.  I am sure there is somewhere online that you can google that error message...  good luck

Comment: You need to use the `TEXT` macro to define your string, e.g. `TEXT("1")` or use the `L` prefix to specify a Unicode string literal as follows: `L"1"`.